# Explain what this mean in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange<ObservableCollection<BaseMdmViewModelCollection>>(() => SubItemsViewModels);
```

Comment: Did you try asking who wrote it (if he is still around)? We could guess but the one who wrote it should know it.

Answer (score 3):

It's making a call to a generic function with signature

`NotifyOfPropertyChange<T>(Func<BaseMdmViewModelCollection>)`

```
() => SubItemsViewModels
```

is identical to

```
delegate { return SubItemsViewModels; }
```

In other words,

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange<ObservableCollection<BaseMdmViewModelCollection>>(() => SubItemsViewModels);
```

is the same as

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange<ObservableCollection<BaseMdmViewModelCollection>>(Foo);
```

where Foo would be

```
private BaseMdmViewModelCollection Foo()
{
    return SubItemsViewModels;
}
```

Comment: What is this then: `() => SubItemsViewModels`

Comment: It's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

In simple terms: When there is a change in the observable collection, return the Sub items view model.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be willing to bet that your `NotifyOfPropertyChange` method is using the `Func` to simply get the name of the property that changed.  This gives you compile-time safety of property changes, which is much more preferable than saying `NotifyPropertyChange("SubItemsViewModels")`.  This approach is used extensively in WPF and Silverlight data bindings, but is also a general purpose pattern that is useful in many scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You have a method 
NotifyOfPropertyChange(Func func), where in your case T1 is BaseMdmViewModelCollection.

SubItemsViewModels is from type ObservableCollection

This is a way to pass any function that returns the collection instead of passing the collection directly.

Cheers,

Gilad